# Startup sequence of Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, power-sequencing

Which would be the startup sequence of a Microcontroller.

Clock - Power - Reset

Power - Clock - Reset

I think it would be the second one because clock is always running, right?
The noises in the environment, would make the crystal oscillation. But without the power to the Micro, the noise signal would not get amplified and we would not get the crystal frequency.

So, Power - Clock - Reset.

Is my understanding right

Comment: That would be dependent on which microcontroller it is. Many have internal clocks and reset circuitry so external is not needed. Are you talking about a specific microcontroller?

Comment: He thinks the sequence matters

Comment: I am just asking in General regarding microcontrollers. But I am currently using NXP5606S

Comment: Related, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940277/584518) for how to do everything proper. It addresses oscillator setup and LVD (low voltage detect) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal sequence (at least in all System-On-Chips I have worked on) is:

1. Power. Without power nothing works so that has to come first.
2. Clock but with reset active. 
   That is because the reset has to be released synchronous to the clock otherwise you will have reset-clock violations on all your registers.
3. Reset release Thus the reset is released (made inactive) last.

A lot of that is hidden in a start-up module which has all asynchronous reset registers. From there you can then generate the reset (synchronous or asynchronous) for the rest of the circuit e.g. an ARM processor core.

---

I use "reset active" to avoid having to distinguish between active low or active high reset. "Active" means the that device is held in reset. In more technical documentation you will often read about 'asserted' (the signal is active) or 'de-asserted' (this signal is inactive).

As to "reset-clock violations" This is the same type of timing violation as set-up and hold time for data. The reset-release and active clock edge are not allowed to change nearly simultaneous. It is an often forgotten requirement but you can find it in the datasheet of registers (e.g. a 74xx74).

Comment: Could you explain your 2nd and 3rd point a little bit briefly. I am using https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf . I am not understanding what you said by "reset active" and reset-clock violations

Comment: @Newbie familiar with timing violations in vlsi ?

Comment: Yes. Setup and Hold time right?

Comment: Apart from "reset-clock violations", without reset the registers may power up in random states, then if clock is applied before reset the MCU will do random stuff. Could be nasty if eg. an I/O pin is controlling something dangerous.